# BNFC generated grammar fails on simplest examples

Tags: language-agnostic, interpreter, formal-languages, bnfc

I would like to write an interpreter in haskell for a simple imperative language.
To do that, I first wrote gramar of that language for the tool BNFC (http://bnfc.digitalgrammars.com/).

Part of that grammar is dedicated to arithmetic expressions, such as:

```
EAdd.     Expr ::= Expr "+" Expr ;
EMinus.   Expr ::= Expr "-" Expr ;
EMul.     Expr ::= Expr "*" Expr ;
ENum.     Expr ::= Integer ;
```

Having just that, I can run the BNFC tool and test it by provided script. It parses arithmetic operations succesfully.

However, if I add another section (let's say with types):

```
Tint.    Type ::= "int" ;
```

And then put the expr secion, arithmetic operations no longer parse (when testing on 1 + 2 it says  "Parse failed... [some tokens here] syntax error at line 1 before 1 + 2")

Why does it happen? How to fix it?

To rephrase:

Why such gramar:

```
TInt.  Type ::=  "int" ;
EAdd.  Expr ::= Expr "+" Expr ;
ENum.  Expr ::= Integer ;
```

does not parse correctly `1 + 1` using bnfc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the absence of an [`entrypoint`](http://bnfc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lbnf.html#entry-point-pragmas) declaration, bnfc will use the first category defined in the grammar as entry point in the test script.

I.e. if you add `Tint. Type ::= "int" ;` at the top of your file, the script generated by bnfc will try to parse a `Type`, not an `Expr`.